# Как прочитать файл несколько раз в Nodejs

Tags: node.js, файлы

Подскажите, как прочитать файл несколько раз в node.js?

Запускаю свой код - виснет:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var id = 1;

while (id < 10) {
  fs.readFile('1.txt', function (error, data) {
    console.log('file:');

    if (error) {
      console.log("!!!");
    }

    console.log('file:' + data);
    id = id + 1;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело тут не в том, что файл нельзя прочитать несколько раз, это как раз без проблем, дело в том, что переменную `id` вы меняете внутри callback-функции.
Меняйте её внутри тела цикла и всё будет работать (не знаю, правда, то ли это, чего вы хотели достичь; я не совсем понял, для чего именно один и тот же файл нужно перечитывать 10 раз).

```
var fs = require('fs');
var id = 1;

while (id < 10) {
  fs.readFile('1.txt', function (error, data) {
    console.log('file:');

    if (error) {
      console.log("!!!");
    }

    console.log('file:' + data);
  });
  id = id + 1;
}
```

Ешё лучше использовать `async`:

```
function readAsync(file, callback) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', callback);
}

async.map(files, readAsync, function(err, results) {
    // results = ['file 1 content', 'file 2 content', ...]
});
```

В данном случае я прохожу по `files`, но, естественно, можно и один и тот же файл перечитывать несколько раз.

Answer (score 1):

Если используется node 0.12+, то можно воспользоваться Promise.

```
function readFile() {
   return Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       return fs.readFile("file.txt", function(err, content){
            if(err) return reject(err);
            resolve(content);
       });
   });
} 

var i, promises = [];
 for(i=0; i<10; i++){
     promises.push(readFile());
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function (contents){
      // contents - массив результатов чтений
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем читать файл 10 раз?

Если вы хотите отслеживать изменения, то лучше использовать `fs.watchFile`.